# Smart parsing string java

Tags: java, regex, parsing

Is there some kind of rule engine or some smart way to do this?

I have a string like this :

```
test 1-2-22
```

SO that I can get these values:

```
name = "test"
part_id = 1
brand_id = 2
count = 22
```

I have more of these so called rules from which I know the format of string.

I was thinking I can do this with regex, but is there a better way of doing this instead?

**Edit:**

I see some very good answers. Maybe I should have been more clear. 
This is not the only string type that I might have, I could have a string like this :

```
test 3-brand 15 – 2
```

Where after parsing it should be :

```
name = "test"
part_id = 2
brand_id = 3
count = 15
```

So I can have different strings and I need to definy a rule/pattern for each of those. What would be good way to do this? Regex is one option for now

Comment: will all Strings have this format?

Answer (score 3):

You can split around both spaces and dashes using the following expression:

```
[ -]
```

Then you will find the different components at indexes starting from `0`.

In Java:

```
String input = "test 1-2-22";
String[] results = input.split("[ -]");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `Pattern regex`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Z]+)\\s*([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)$");
```

Then this code should work:

```
String line = "test 1-2-22";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Z]+)\\s*([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
if (matcher.find()) {
   System.out.printf("name:%s, part_id:%s, brand_id:%s, count:%s%n",
       matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2), matcher.group(3), matcher.group(4) );
}
```

Comment: how would I use your pattern with named group matching with new java 7 JDL

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, suitable `split` operations (or other manual string processing) is probably going to be easiest, as you have the whitespace and the dashes to look for explicitly.

For more complex patterns you can look into `antlr` for tokenising this into (for example) one `identifier` and three `number` tokens and then parsing it, but that seems to be overkill here.  (This would give you a 'rule engine', thugh.)

In general:  you may want to read up on *parsing* and *context-free grammars* for this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
String s = "test 1-2-22";
String[] vars = s.split("[ -]");
String name = vars[0];
String part_id = vars[1];
String brand_id = vars[2];
String count  = vars[3];
```

This will split the string if a space or "-" occurs. 
you could then convert the ids and count to int if required.